# Creating an Updating trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have to create a trigger that calculate the the quantity in stock and this is my first one on PostgreSQL.

When entering the quantity bought at a Provider (Fournisseur) or a delivery at a client, the quantity has to be updated.

I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CalculQStockProduit(String)
    WHEN UPDATE QuantiteEnStock ON Produit
         BEGIN QuantiteEnStock = QuantiteEnStock-Quantite
         OR    QuantiteEnStock = QuantiteEnStock+Quantite
```

I know this wrong, not enough accurate. Can you help me learning how to create an accurate and right trigger?

The related database scheme in UML is (in French, unfortunately):

[image: UML description of the database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you have to create a trigger function that will perform the calculations and the use it in a trigger.

Example:

```
Create or replace function CalculQStockProduit() returns trigger as $$
begin;
 update QuantiteEnStock set NEW.QuantiteEnStock = NEW.QuantiteEnStock-NEW.Quantite;
return NEW;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


Create trigger trgCalculQStockProduit after update on Produit
for each row execute procedure calc();
```

I would refer to trigger function in postgresql manual for better understanding

This is just a sample so you will have to work out the calculations needed.

[PG Trigger functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-trigger.html)

Choose according to your postgres version.

I have used plpgsql as language but there are various options. plpgsql, sql, plv8 etc etc

Comment: Thank you very much! But it gives me the following error:

`ERREUR:  syntax error on « $1 »
LINE 1: update QuantiteEnStock set  $1  =  $2 - $3 `